# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x^2}-\cos x^{\sqrt{2}}}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

> Find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x^2}-\cos x^{\sqrt{2}}}{x^2}$

Using Taylor series:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x^2}-\cos x^{\sqrt{2}}}{x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x^2+O(x^{2n}))-(1-\frac{x^{2\sqrt{2}}}{2}+O(x^{\sqrt{2}(2n+1)})}{x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{2x^2+x^{2\sqrt{2}}}{2}}{x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{2x^2+x^{2\sqrt{2}}}{2x^2}$$

How to evaluate this limit?

Comment: Derivative of top and bottom?

Comment: Divide the numerator and denominator by $x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. You may just write, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\frac{e^{x^2}-\cos (x^{\sqrt{2}})}{x^2}=\frac{x^2(1+\frac12x^{2\sqrt{2}-2})+O(x^4)}{x^2}=1+\frac12x^{2\sqrt{2}-2}+O(x^2) \longrightarrow 1.
$$
In fact, $x^{2\sqrt{2}}$ is **negligible** comparing to $x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from where you left off, we divide the numerator and denominator by $x^2$ we obtain $\frac{2+x^{2\sqrt{2}-2}}{2}$. Now $\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{2+x^{2\sqrt{2}-2}}{2}}=\frac{2+0}{2}=1$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the function $\cos x^{\sqrt{2}}$ is only defined for $x>0$, so we can set $t=x^2$, hence $x=t^{1/2}$ and $x^{\sqrt{2}}=t^{\sqrt{2}/2}$. Thus the limit becomes, where $a=\sqrt{2}/2$,
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{e^t-\cos(t^a)}{t}
$$
and we can apply l'Hôpital:
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}(e^t+at^{a-1}\sin(t^a))=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\left(e^t+at^{2a-1}\frac{\sin(t^a)}{t^a}\right)=1
$$
because $2a-1>0$